# What are the physical limitations on energy density for a useful, safe battery, and are we anywhere near them?

Tags: energy, density, batteries

Energy storage seems to be a fairly major bottle neck in technological development at the moment, especially for important things like clean-energy powered transport, but also for consumer goods. Are there physical limitations of batteries for these and similar uses? Lithum-ion batteries seem to be the go-to for these applications at the moment, likely because of their [high energy to weight ratio](http://www.allaboutbatteries.com/Battery-Energy.html). Even they sometimes explode, so I guess safety is somewhat of a grey area, but for the purposes assume standard-ish safety margins. Are Lithium-ion batteries approaching such physical limitations?

Comment: I suspect this is an engineering question, rather than a conceptual physics one; and that would make it off-topic here. I'd welcome it over on [Sustainability.SE] though, where we can take engineering questions about sustainable technology.

Comment: Hrm, that depends on the answers. I'm looking for theoretical physical limitations as answers. I imagine engineering limitations would be substantially lower.

Comment: I'm not sure "safe" can be conceptual physics rather than engineering. Is a lump of coal safe? A can of diesel? A canister of CNG? A cylinder of highly compressed hydrogen? A lump of plutonium? Lots of energy densities to choose from there ...

Comment: ok, maybe this should be moved to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ?